# Parsing an integer from a specific type of ID string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, slice

Get ID variables from a textbox, these variables change =

> SC00021

```
var IdCode1 = "SC00021"; 
var res = IdCode1.slice(5, 7);
```

Get

> 21

**How can I do to automatically detect the position after the 0's?**

Comment: If you're interested in Javascript, this shouldn't have a Java tag. Totally different language.

Comment: Neither a jQuery tag for that matter

Comment: You want to detect the position or you want to get the number (e.g. 21)?

Answer (score 0):

Use some regex!

The pattern used here `/SC0+(\d+)$` looks for "SC" immediately followed by one or more zeroes, and then fetches any digits after that. Note that this is pretty easily configurable to handle additional cases (ids that start with other letters/patterns, ids with no leading zeroes etc).

Here's an interactive snippet to see it in action. The meat is really the second 2 lines of the javascript function.

```js
function parseId() {
    var id = document.getElementById("the_id").value;
    var regex = /SC0+(\d+)$/;
    var match = regex.exec(id)[1];
    document.getElementById("result").value = match;
}
```

```html
<input id="the_id" value="SC00021" type="text" /> <input type="button" onclick="parseId()" value="Parse!"><br />
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="result" value="" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: Work's very well

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first index of "0" and the string and increment that index until that position is not "0" and then return the remainder of the string:

```
var IdCode1 = "SC00021"; 
var idx = IdCode1.indexOf("0"); 
for(;IdCode1[++idx]=="0";);
var res = IdCode1.substring(idx);
console.log(res);
```